# Run Java task in ant using a different JRE

Tags: java, ant

I try to execute a java class using Ant.
I used the task

```
<java... >
```

But when it runs I get this:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: mypackage/myTest: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
...
```

My ant is not running on Java 1.7. 
I saw that for a javac task, you can specify `target` to set the java version.
Is there a way to specify a specific JDK to be used with the java task?

Comment: the version that runs the class must be higher or equals to the version the class has been compiled with

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used the following:

```
<java classname="mypackage.myTest"
          jvm="${java_17.home}/bin/java.exe" fork="true">
```

The `jvm` can determine the command used for executing java. I gave it the path to my 1.7 JDK.
It's important to have `fork="true"`, otherwise ant won't run a different java...

Answer (score 2):

specify java compiler you want while doing javac in ANT build.xml

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${dist.dir.classes}" compiler="javac1.6" executable="D:\jdk1.6.2_05\bin\javac"  />
```

Comment: You will need java 7 for this, I think

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a way to make it work for a JAVA task, not a JAVAC. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Thanks anyway...